# Null Pointer Exception at EOF

Tags: java, bufferedreader, fileinputstream

So I'm currently getting a null pointer on the last line of this method. From everything I've read on others with this issue, using the `while ((lineIn = myReader.readLine()) != null)` should be stopping the file once it has nothing left, but it doesn't seem to do that. Instead I end up catching a NPE. I can't figure out exactly why that is. Any advice would be appreciated! I currently band-aid the issue by using another `catch (NullPointerException)` statement, but I don't feel that that's an adequate solution.

```
BufferedReader myReader;

        try {
            FileInputStream fileInStream = new FileInputStream(
                    fileLocation);
            InputStreamReader fileInputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                    fileInStream, "UTF-16");
            myReader = new BufferedReader(fileInputStreamReader);

            String lineIn = "";

            // Read the next line until there aren't any left
            while ((lineIn = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
                //Do stuff with line
            }
            System.out.println("done");
            // Close the file connections now that the read is done.
            fileIn.close();
            myReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
```

}

Comment: close the reader in finally block: `finally { if(fileIn != null) fileIn.close(); if(myReader != null) myReader.close(); }`

Comment: What do you do inside of `//Do stuff with line`?

Comment: @Zhuinden Closing `fileInStream` is enough.

Comment: @m0skit0, actually closing myReader (not touching) FileInputStream is the right thing to do.

Comment: @FedericoPonzi Just String parsing, nothing to do with the input streams :)

Answer (score 3):

**Null Pointer should never be caught it should be fixed. You do not want them to propagate to the remaining parts of your code.**

Also ensure you are closing your file. Add a finally block and close those files resources. This way if an exception is caught you will still close your file.

Comment: try-with-resources (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) is the approach.

Comment: yup , from the doc it seems like try-with-resource is java 7 and above. For all other versions use the try with finally.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was I hadn't properly closed my file readers from previous operations. Thank you guys.